# Integral of non-negative measurable function $g$ such that $\mu(g>0) =0$

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Lately I've been having a lot of difficulty with measure theory. I've been struggling to prove even the most basic sounding facts. I suspect it is because I have difficult understanding how statements about the measure translate to statements about the integral.  Here is an example:

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ be a measure space and $g: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ a non-negative measurable function. Let $A = \{x \in \Omega : g(x)>0 \}$ and suppose that $\mu(A)  = 0$, then $$\int_\Omega g \,
d\mu = 0$$

I'd like to just work from the definition of the integral as a limit of simple functions. So let $g_n$ be a sequence of simple functions converging (point-wise) to $g$. Then $$g_n = \sum_i c_i \mathbb{1}_{B_i}$$ for some disjoint $B_i$ such that $\Omega = \bigcup_i B_i$. Hence $$\int_\Omega g_n \, d\mu = \sum_ic_i\mu(B_i)
$$

And this is where I'm stuck. I think I want to translate my information about $\mu(A)$ to a statement about $\mu(B_i)$ but I'm unsure how to go about this. Intuitively, one would think that as $n\to \infty$ eventually $B_i \subseteq A$ which would force the measure to be zero of course but I'm not sure how to rigourously prove this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can take $g_n$ such that $0 \leq g_n \leq g$. We may also suppose $c_i>0$ for  all $i$. Then $B_i \subset A$ for every $i$ becasue $g_n(x) >0$ implies $g(x) >0$. Hence $\mu (B_i)=0$ for each $i$ which gives $\int g_n d\mu=0$. Letting $n \to \infty$ we get $\int g d\mu=0$.